# .htaccess one directory with extensions, the others without

Tags: php, .htaccess, redirect

I've managed, with help from you, to get this .htaccess, but i also needing 1 directory with extenions. For example: www.url.com/beheer/index.php, so everything under /beheer has to be with extensions.

This is the current .htaccess:

```
# remove trailing slash if not directory
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)/$ /$1 [L,R=301]

# remove index.php
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^[A-Z]{3,}\ /(.*)index\.php/?([^\?\ ]*)
RewriteRule ^ /%1%2 [L,R=301]

# remove php extension
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^[A-Z]{3,}\ /(.*)\.php($|\ |\?)
RewriteRule ^ /%1 [L,R=301]

RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^([^\.]*)(\.php)?(\?*)$ index.php/$1$3 [L,QSA]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add this to your .htaccess. It will do nothing to requests, made to the /beheer folder.

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/beheer
RewriteRule .* - [L]
```

Answer (score 0):

Works :) and can i also exclude a few scripts from the htaccess? so that a few scripts are have the .php extension?